# Vuejs Unit Test - Backing Mocks with Tests

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js, vuex

I am writing unit testing for a vuejs 2 application that uses Vuex as a store. I have the following pattern in many of my components:

example component thing.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ thing.label }}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'thing',
    data() { return { } },
    computed: {
       thing () {
         return this.$store.state.thing;
       }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Example Store State:

```
export const state = {
    thing: { label: 'test' }
};
```

Example Unit for Thing.vue:

```
describe('thing ', () => {

  const storeMock = new Vuex.Store( state: { thing: { label: 'test' } } );

  it('should pull thing from store', () => {
      const Constructor = Vue.extend(thing);
      const component new Constructor({ store }).$mount();

      expect(component.thing).toEqual({ label: 'test' });
  });

});
```

Example Unit test for Store:

```
import store from './store';

describe('Vuex store ', () => {

  it('should have a thing object', () => {
      expect(store.state.thing).toEqual({ label: 'test' });
  });

});
```

There is a huge problem with this pattern.  When another developer refractors the store state, they will see the Store test fail, but because the thing unit test is based on a mocked version of the store that test with continue to pass, even though that component will never work. There isn't a good way to know a refactor invalidated a Mock.

So how do people unit test this type of dependence?

One way would be to cheat a little on the unit test and use the real store state, but then it isn't really a unit test.  The other way is rely on integration testing to catch the mock - store mismatch, but that feels like it would be painful to debug why the unit tests pass but the integration tests are failing.

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing is using the actual store.  Because the store state is just an object we figured it was acceptable.

We also use the store getters, actions and mutations as templates for jasmine spyies.

```
// Vuex needs polyfill
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise';
polyfill();
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import test from 'app/components/test.vue';
import module from 'app/store/modules/module';


describe('Spec for Test.vue', () => {
    var props;
    var state;
    var actions;
    var mutations;
    var getters;
    var store;

    beforeEach( () => {
        jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
        props = { };

        // Don't change the modules
        state = Object.assign({}, module.state);
        actions = Object.assign({}, module.actions);
        mutations = Object.assign({}, module.mutations);
        getters = Object.assign({}, module.getters);

        // Add require global actions, mutations, and getters here...
        actions.globalActionHere = 'anything'; // this turns into a spy

        // Update State with required fields
        state.defaults = { id: 1 }   // default expected when the component loads

        // Replace modules copies with mocks
        actions = jasmine.createSpyObj('actions', actions);
        mutations = jasmine.createSpyObj('mutations', mutations);
        getters = jasmine.createSpyObj('getters', getters);

        store = new Vuex.Store( { state: { module: state }, getters, actions, mutations } );
    } );

    it('should have a name of test', () => {
        const Constructor = Vue.extend(thing);
        const component new Constructor({ store, props }).$mount();

        expect(component.$options.name).toBe('test');
    });

});
```

Note the part

```
jasmine.createSpyObj('actions', actions);
```

Jasmine spies will use the module to create spyies for each of the methods, which is very useful.